# Execute windows cmd command on all files in directory

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, logparser

Very simply, I want to execute a command on every file in a directory, one at a time, and log the output of that command.

I wrote the following batch script:

```
pushd C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2
for %%x in (C:\templogs\3\C\IISLogFiles\W3SVC3\deduped*.log) do (
   LogParser "SELECT * INTO weblog FROM %%~dpnx" -i:W3C -o:SQL -server:localhost -database:testdb -driver:"SQL Server" -createTable:OFF >> input.out   
)
popd
```

When I execute it in the command prompt, all it does it copy paste those commands exactly as is. Nothing executes. any idea?

Comment: Do you need to turn echo off or something first? Just guessing not used powershell

Comment: echo on./off should not matter. The code jsut does not execute

Comment: Craig Stewart's right. If you don't `echo off` or use `@`, everything in the batch file is displayed in the command prompt. Are you certain it's not executing?

Comment: @AndyArismendi: No, `%%~dpnx` is the `%%x` loop variable, only with modifiers (`~dpn`). The double percents must be retained.

Comment: @AndriyM thx removed my comment.

Comment: Could you show how the output looks in the console window? Also, did you take a look at the `input.out` file that your batch script is supposed to generate? Is that file empty or does it contain anything?

Answer (score 0):

The only situation when that would be the case is when:

```
dir C:\templogs\3\C\IISLogFiles\W3SVC3\deduped*.log
```

... would come back blank. Could you please double check that this path actually contains files you want to process...?

I've tried it several ways and always got expected result (LogParser is not recognized in my case), unless I've tried on the path that did not existed on my system...

Answer (score 0):

How about just executing LogParser as:

```
LogParser "SELECT * INTO weblog FROM C:\templogs\3\C\IISLogFiles\W3SVC3\deduped*.log" -i:W3C -o:SQL -server:localhost -database:testdb -driver:"SQL Server" -createTable:OFF
```